# Selecting count by row combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm strugling with what on the first sight appeared to be simple SQL query :)

So I have following table which has three columns: PlayerId, Gender, Result (all of type integer).

What I'm trying to do, is to select distinct players of gender 2 (male) with number of each results.
There are about 50 possible results, so new table should have 51 columns:

|PlayerId | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | 50 |

So I would like to see how many times each individual male (gender 2) player got specific result.

*** In case question is still not entirely clear to you: After each game I insert a row with a player ID, gender and result (from 1 - 50) player achieved in that game. Now I'd like to see how many times each player achieved specfic results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are 50 results and you want them in columns, then you are talking about a pivot.  I tend to do these with conditional aggregation:

```
select player,
       sum(case when result = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as result_00,
       sum(case when result = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as result_01,
       . . .
       sum(case when result = 50 then 1 else 0 end) as result_50
from t
group by player;
```

You can choose a particular gender if you like, with `where gender = 2`.  But why not calculate all at the same time?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what i needed, but I had to replace "select gender" with "select player" and "group by gender" with "group by player" to get what I initially wanted to. I'm not calculating all at the same time, because I have cca 200 milion in my primary table and I assume limiting to specific gender will be quicker (gender I want to filter is 10% of all rows)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
select  player, result, count(*)  
from your_table 
where Gender = 2
group by player, result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select PleyerId from tablename where result = 'specific result you want' and gender = 2 group by PleyerId
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use pivoting:

```
;with cte as(Select * from t
             Where gender = 2)
Select * from cte
Pivot(count(gender) for result in([1],[2],[3],....,[50]))p
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8dad5/3

One note: keeping gender in scores table is a bad idea. Better make a separate table for players and keep gender there.